# sfp-25g-sr-s alternatives

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-nexus

I work at a media company and we have a room where we're essentially having a spine leaf topology implemented for our network. Now there's 4 spine switches and 6 leaf switches, the sfp we're using are the 25g-sr-s modules, but I've been told we can save money by having a cross connect since the switches will be in the same room.

[image]

Can someone help me explain how this would work? that's if it's possible at all

Cheerio

Comment: Hello Mark! Could you please attach a scheme that will help better understand what you have now and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @AndreyProkhorov Added in diagram. the leafs and spines will all be in one room, most likely in the same network rack.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean under "a cross connect"?

Comment: @AndreyProkhorov i'm not sure as i hadn't come accross that term myself, but i'm assuming it another way to connect the switches without having to use the SFP modules.

Comment: You can save money by purchasing so-called DAC (direct attach cable), but it has it's own limitations and most of the time requires that equipment is located realy close one to each other. Length of those cables are often below 10m. Also there could be limitations based on your switches (they can support as example of maximum 2-3m DAC on 25G).

Comment: @AndreyProkhorov Thanks, i've done some research and the DAC will be fine, can you post your last comment as an answer so i can mark this answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save money by purchasing so-called DAC (direct attach cable), but it has it's own limitations and most of the time requires that equipment is located realy close one to each other. Length of those cables are often below 10m.

Also there could be limitations based on your switches (they can support as example of maximum 2-3m DAC on 25G). I suggest you to spend some time and maybe ask your integrator (if you have one) or search info about available DAC for your equipment and their limitations.